# Steady-state solution of Fokker-Planck DE

Tags: differential-equations, steady-state

I have this differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\tau_s v^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial v}(v^3+v_c^3)f + S$$

It is a [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) that describes collisional slowing down of fast ions in plasma physics: $f(v,t)$ is the distribution function of the fast ions, $S(v)$ is a source term and $v$ is the velocity of the ions. Now, I have three problems concerning this equation. Given $S$, for example 
$$S=\frac{S_0}{4\pi v^2}\delta(v-v0),$$
I think that the steady state can be found solving the DE: 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}(v^3+v_c^3)f =-\frac{\tau_s S_0}{4\pi}\delta(v-v0)$$
by integrating both sides of equation in the range $[v_l, v_0]$ where $v_l > 0$ because I don't want particle faster than the born energy $v0$ and slower than the loss velocity limit $v_l$. Is it correct (and could you write here the solution?) (1)? If so, it seems to me that the solution would be a *negative* distribution function $f$ that is actually meaning less (2). Acknowledged that a steady state exist, this means that the time-dependent solution $f(v,t)$ of the original Fokker-Planck equation should reach the steady state after a large enough amount of time. But if I calculate numerically the time evolution of $f(v,t)$ it does not reach any steady state (3)! It just grows bigger each time step. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: $f$ is a probability distribution, it *cannot* be negative.

Comment: I guess the problem is the distribution specified by the equation cannot be normalized.  With change of variables $u = v^3 + v_c^3$ and $u_0 = v_0^3 + v_c^3$, we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{3}{\tau_s}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(uf) + \frac{3S_0}{4\pi}\delta(u - u_0).$$  Now if we integrate over $u$, we get $$0 = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int f du = 0 + \frac{3 S_0}{4 \pi},$$ which is an equation that is impossible to balance for $S_0 \ne 0$. Are you sure the equation is typed correctly?